# PostgreSql : using a statement as case condition

Tags: postgresql, case-when

when i use a statement as **case condition** it always returns *false*;

```
select * from table order by (case when (true) then id else 1/0 end)  desc -- works 
select * from table order by (case when (select true) then id else 1/0 end)  desc -- exception
select * from table order by (case when (1=1) then id else 1/0 end)  desc -- works
select * from table order by (case when (select 1=1) then id else 1/0 end)  desc -- exception
```

what is wrong with that condition?

Answer (score 1):

The `CASE WHEN` expects a `boolean` result from the condition as per the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-conditional.html):

> Each ***condition*** is an expression that returns a boolean result.

The `SELECT` statements return a **relation** (yes, with a single row having a single column with a `boolean` type and a value of `TRUE` but that is still not a `boolean`).

Comment: ok, is there any way to convert that reletion to boolean ! i tried to convert it with ***::boolean*** operator. it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, the select statement returns a relation but the single returned value from a [scalar subquery `(select...)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-SCALAR-SUBQUERIES) is used in the expression.

Answer (score 1):

The subquery `(select true)` returns a boolean value:

```
select (select true);
 bool 
------
 t
```

And the `case` works:

```
select (case when (select true) then 1 else 0 end);
 case 
------
    1
```

The problem is that the `else` expression is always evaluated:

```
select (case when (select true) then 1 else 1/0 end);
ERROR:  division by zero
```

In instead divide by the condition casted to integer:

```
select 1/true::integer;
 ?column? 
----------
        1

select 1/false::integer;
ERROR:  division by zero
```

Your sample code would be:

```
select *
from table
order by id/(my_condition)::integer desc
```

BTW are you sure you want to raise an exception?

Comment: "*the else expression is always evaluated*" [contradicts with the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE): "*If the condition's result is true, the value of the CASE expression is the result that follows the condition, **and the remainder of the CASE expression is not processed***"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name When the condition involves a subselect that is not true as shown in my example.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That wording is not clear. What is _the remainder of the CASE expression_? The other `when` conditions?